# how to ignore a certain word in wordcloud?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am making a word cloud of a novel but it is the Gutenberg version and I want it ignore the word Gutenberg which appears frequently enough in the margins of the document.

```
import textract
import difflib
import nltk
import re

text = textract.process('ethanfrome.pdf', method = 'tesseract')
book1 = text.decode()

from wordcloud import WordCloud

long_string = (book1)

wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color="white", max_words=30000, contour_width=10, contour_color= 'steelblue')

wordcloud.generate(long_string)

wordcloud.to_image()
```

Comment: what do you have in `book1`? If you have list then you could use `for`-loop to filter it . If you have string then you can try `.replace("Gutenberg", "")`

Comment: I think you can add `stopwords=["Gutenberg"]` to `WordCloud(...)`.